# How to dynamically allocate screen space for two ListViews on a single page?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a TO-DO app and want to emulate how Google's Tasks App is working.

[image]

I have two ListViews, the first ListView contains the tasks which are pending, the second ListView contains the tasks which are marked as completed.

How can I display both on one screen in a way that the ExpansionTile only appears if there are completed tasks?
How can I accomplish that both Lists are scrollable but without having a fixed screen space?

My current code works only if the List contains a few tasks, once it outgrows the screen space, I get an overflow error and it is no longer possible to scroll up or down.

`ListItemsBuilder` returns a `ListView.separated()`.

```dart
return StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
  stream: getJobsStream(database),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
        final pendingJobs = snapshot.data.where((job) => !job.jobDone).toList();
        final completedJobs = snapshot.data.where((job) => job.jobDone).toList();
        return Column(
          children: [
            ListItemsBuilder<Job>(
              itemList: pendingJobs,
              itemBuilder: (context, job) => Dismissible(
                key: Key('job-${job.id}'),
                background: dismissBackground(job),
                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                onDismissed: (direction) => _markJobAsCompleted(context, job),
                child: JobListTile(
                  job: job,
                  onTap: () => JobEntriesPage.show(context, job),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            completedJobs.isNotEmpty ? ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Tareas Completadas (${completedJobs.length.toString()})'),
              children: [
                ListItemsBuilder<Job>(
                  itemList: completedJobs,
                  itemBuilder: (context, job) => Dismissible(
                    key: Key('job-${job.id}'),
                    background: dismissBackground(job),
                    direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                    onDismissed: (direction) => _deleteJob(context, job),
                    child: JobListTile(
                      job: job,
                      onTap: () => JobEntriesPage.show(context, job),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ) : Container(),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return EmptyContent();
      }
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return EmptyContent(
        title: 'Ocurrio un error',
        // message: 'No se puede cargar a las Tareas ahora mismo',
        message: 'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
      );
    }
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Column, you could place your two lists inside a `ListView` with `shrinkWrap: true`.

[image]

### Full source code:

```
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

part '66446599.tasks.freezed.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tasks = useProvider(tasksProvider.state);
    final pendingTasks = tasks.whereNot((task) => task.completed).toList();
    final completedTasks = tasks.where((task) => task.completed).toList();
    final pendingTasksExpanded = useState(true);
    final completedTasksExpanded = useState(true);
    print('Rebuild');
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('Tasks (${pendingTasks.length})'),
            initiallyExpanded: pendingTasksExpanded.value,
            onExpansionChanged: (expanded) =>
                pendingTasksExpanded.value = expanded,
            children: pendingTasks.isEmpty
                ? [ListTile(title: Text("You're all clear, no pending task!"))]
                : [
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: pendingTasks.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => context
                            .read(tasksProvider)
                            .toggleCompleted(pendingTasks[index].id),
                        child: ListTile(title: Text(pendingTasks[index].name)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
          ),
          if (completedTasks.isNotEmpty)
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Completed Tasks (${completedTasks.length})'),
              initiallyExpanded: completedTasksExpanded.value,
              onExpansionChanged: (expanded) =>
                  completedTasksExpanded.value = expanded,
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: completedTasks.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => context
                        .read(tasksProvider)
                        .toggleCompleted(completedTasks[index].id),
                    child: ListTile(title: Text(completedTasks[index].name)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

final tasksProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TasksNotifier>((ref) => TasksNotifier());

class TasksNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Task>> {
  TasksNotifier([List<Task> state]) : super(state ?? tasks);

  toggleCompleted(int id) {
    state = state
        .map((task) =>
            task.id == id ? task.copyWith(completed: !task.completed) : task)
        .toList();
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class Task with _$Task {
  const factory Task({int id, String name, @Default(false) bool completed}) =
      _Task;
}

final faker = Faker();
final tasks =
    List.generate(20, (index) => Task(id: index, name: faker.food.dish()));
```